# Create http session in filter

Tags: java, httpsession

My xhtml web pages are called from an external system using a simple request, I suppose to check if the user name - given from the request - is valid or not, if valid he suppose to get to the home page, other than that he is redirected to the external system. I created a filter to get the request:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;


    // skip the resources library
    if (!req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) {
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP
                                                                                // 1.1.
        res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
    }

    Object attr = req.getParameter("user");
    String language = (String) req.getParameter("language");

    if (attr != null && language != null) {
        // check user in db
        String userAdmin = (String) attr;

        ResultStatus result = myDao.findUser(userAdmin);
        if (result.getStatus().equals(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS)) {
            // User is logged in, so just continue request.
            User user = new User();
            user.setAccountId(result.getAccount().getAccountId());



            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {
            // User is not logged in, so redirect to index.
            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/test.xhtml");
        }
    } else {
        // User is not logged in, so redirect to index.
        res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/test.xhtml");
    }
}
```

I need to create session for the user in the filter if he is a valid user, so I can get the user object at any back bean.

Comment: You have access to the request in `req` variable, just call `req.getSession` and you'll get the `HttpSession` to store/restore/invalidate the user.

Comment: I did this `req.getSession().setAttribute(USER_TOKEN, newUser);` to set the user and this `FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
   User flag = (User) session.getAttribute(USER_TOKEN);` to get it at a baking bean, is this right??

Comment: You don't need to use `FacesContext` in a Servlet Filter.

Comment: I'll put it simple: JSF is irrelevant for your problem. Use plain `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpSession` to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To set it just do this :

```
req.getSession().getServletContext().setAttribute(LoginFilter.USER_KEY, user);
                    chain.doFilter(req, res);
```

To get it :

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
User user = (User) request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute(LoginFilter.USER_KEY);
```